# Rails routes for a static landing page if user not logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my application I am using the Devise authentication gem which works really well. I also have built a static landing page which I currently have in the `/public` directory.

I can of course browser to `localhost:3000/landing` and see the page (as per the route below) but what I'm trying to achieve but cannot seem to figure out is how to setup my `routes.rb` file so that the `landing.html` file is the root, but when a user is logged in, their root becomes `companies#index`.

**Here is my routes.rb file**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  
  devise_for :users
  get 'dashboard/index'
  
  get '/landing', :to => redirect('/landing.html')
  
  root 'companies#index'
  
  resources :companies do
    resources :shareholders
    resources :captables do
      post :subscribe_to_captable
      resources :events do
        post :lock_event
        post :unlock_event
        resources :transactions
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Here is my application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to put the redirect inside your `CompaniesController.rb` `index` method do this.

CompanesController.rb (or whatever it is called)

```
def index
  unless user_signed_in?
    redirect_to landing_pages_path (or whatever the name of the route is)
  end
end
```

Then change the route in the `routes.rb` file.

```
get '/landing', to: 'companies#landing' * change companies here to the name of the controller holding the landing page's method if it is not in the companies controller.
```

Comment: Ah, so I don't actually have any controller for the landing page - it's simply an html file in the /public folder. Should probably change that. Thanks for your help!